# How to get the reverse average of a string? - python

Tags: python

I have a function that provides the average value of the digits in the string until a letter appears.

However, I'm having trouble reversing this string so rather than counting from the start of the string, I wanted to calculate the average from the end of the string to the beginning of the string[-1 to 0] before a letter appears.

For example, using n = "34B22" in the function results in 3.5 ( (3+4)/2 ) but I'm actually looking to find the reverse (2+2)/2 = 2.

```
def AverageReverse(n):
    result = 0
    count = 0
    for x in (n):
        if x.isdigit():
            result += int(x)
            count += 1
        if x.islower():
            break
        if x.isupper():
            break
    return float(result/count) if result > 0 else 0.0
```

`

Comment: `for x in (reversed(n)) `
reversed flips the string.

Comment: I'd just copy the string char by char into a int array, Starting at the end. That way you will get a parse error when it isn't a  number. Then you can just get the average of your int array. 
It's alot more readable, I don't know about speed.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse n before calculating the average. Do this to reverse the string:-

```
>>> n
'34B22'
>>> n[::-1]
'22B43'
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `n[::-1]` to reverse

```
def AverageReverse(n):
    result = 0
    count = 0
    for x in (n[::-1]):
        if x.isdigit():
            result += int(x)
            count += 1
        if x.islower():
            break
        if x.isupper():
            break
    return float(result/count) if result > 0 else 0.0
```